# Removing checkboxes dynamically added to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, checkbox

I am using the following code to dynamically create a set of checkboxes based on user input from dropdown list. It does not delete the previous selections when the user select another option from the dropdown list.

It only deletes the checkboxes but not the description attached to the check box. I am unable to find the error with the code. Appreciate your help.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#sel_LearnA').change(function(event) {  

    var $learnA=$("select#sel_LearnA").val();

$.get('actionDataSelect',{LAreaID:$learnA},function(responseJson) {   

    // remove existing checkboxes
    $('#somediv').children().remove();

    // add checkboxes to the div
    $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) { // Iterate over the JSON array.
        $('#somediv').append("<input type='checkbox' value='"+ item.keyCode + "' />" + item.keyCode + "</br>");
    });
});

    });

});
```

And my jsp looks like,

```
<div id="somediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.children()` gets only the element nodes of the parent, not the text nodes

Try empty()

```
$('#somediv').empty();
```

or just .html('')

```
$('#somediv').html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty function resets div.

```
$( "#yourDivId" ).empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the error in your code.

The description is not attached to the checkbox.

```
$('#somediv').append("<input type='checkbox' value='"+ item.keyCode + "' />" + item.keyCode + "</br>");
```

You are closing the checkbox and the description is given after. So .remove will remove the checkbox, not the description.

Put the checkbox and description inside a label and remove the label.

This will definitely work.

```
$('#somediv').append("<label><input type='checkbox' value='"+ item.keyCode + "' />" + item.keyCode + "</label></br>");
```